# Messed up/garbled strings in settings when cherry picking feature into LineageOS

Tags: android, settings, lineageos

I'm new to ROM development and decided I wanted to add a feature to my LineageOS builds to change the height of the back gesture. I've found that cherry picking these 2 commits into frameworks/base and packages/apps/Settings and resolving some conflicts successfully gets the feature into my ROM.

https://gerrit.omnirom.org/#/c/android_frameworks_base/+/35407/

https://gerrit.omnirom.org/#/c/android_packages_apps_Settings/+/35408/1

After building the feature seems to work just fine, but I'm getting this weird issue where the strings in my settings app don't make any sense. The picture below should clarify the issue I'm experiencing.

For example, where it says "smallest width" it should say "Developer options".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/efiTJ.png

I know this isn't much to go of off, but I'm just very confused. The cherry pick was applied almost without issues and I have no idea how it could be affecting these strings. Any insight would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone running in to this issue, this was fixed by doing a clean build. Do this by removing out/ directory or running `make clean`.